# Как редактировать строку в функции? (чистый си)

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели, адрес

Дело такое...
В теле программы объявлена "строка":

```
char *line = "";
```

Далее в функции я хочу динамически выделять память для line. Без функции весь этот код работает прекрасно:

```
line = (char*)malloc(2);
line[0] = ' ';
for (int i = 1; ((c = getchar()) != '\n'); i++) {
tmp = line;
line = (char*)malloc(i + 2);
strcpy(line, tmp);
line[i] = c;
line[i + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Но как только я пытаюсь внести это в функцию, все крашится. А точнее внутри функции все шикарно. Строка принимает значения, память выделяется. Но при выходе из функции все полученные значения теряются. Хотя в функцию я эту строку подаю через указатель: `(char *line)`

Так вот.. Сам вопрос. Как правильно мне эту "строку" подать в функцию? Один человек посоветовал "указателем на указатель", но не совсем понимаю, что он имеет ввиду. Разъясните, пожалуйста:) Я новичок в этом деле

Comment: Так покажите, как вы подаёте строку в функцию.

Comment: Сама функция:
void getstring(char *line) {
 char *tmp = NULL;
 char c = 0;
 line = (char*)malloc(2);
 line[0] = ' ';
 for (int i = 1; ((c = getchar()) != '\n'); i++) {
  tmp = line;
  line = (char*)malloc(i + 2);
  strcpy(line, tmp);
  line[i] = c;
  line[i + 1] = '\0';
 }
}

Comment: А как правильно подать - не знаю) Пробовал все способы.. Просто перебирал

Comment: getstring(line);
getstring(&line);
getstring(*line);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию можно передать указатель на указатель. И изменить в функции указатель на строку `line` (из `main`) через этот самый указатель на указатель:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char **pline)
{
    char *line, *tmp;
    char c;
    line = (char *)malloc(2);
    line[0] = ' ';
    for (int i = 1; ((c = getchar()) != '\n'); i++)
    {
        tmp = line;
        line = (char *)malloc(i + 2);
        strcpy(line, tmp);
        line[i] = c;
        line[i + 1] = '\0';
    }
    *pline = line;
}

int main()
{
    char *line;
    func(&line);
    puts(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь происходит примерно следующее:

Указатель на строку `*line` в `main` - это  число которое храниться где-то в памяти. Получается `**line` - это указатель на ячейку памяти, где храниться этот самый указатель на строку `*line`.

В функцию `func` передаем `&line` указатель на `*line`. И меняем его следующим образом: `*pline = line`.

Операция `*pline` разыменовывает указатель `pline` на `line` из `main` и меняет его на значение `line` из `func`.

Comment: Спасибо, @pank )) Все работает)

Comment: @mr_kosten, рад помочь, но на будущее комментарии к ответам больше предназначены для улучшения ответа, а не для благодарности :)

Answer (score 1):

Давайте подсмотрим подробно, что происходит

```
line = (char*)malloc(2); // выделили памяти на два символа (байта).
line[0] = ' '; // первый инициализировали, а вот второй - нет...
for (int i = 1; ((c = getchar()) != '\n'); i++) {
tmp = line; // запомнили указатель! Строку не копировали
line = (char*)malloc(i + 2); // выделили на два байта больше памяти, чем i
strcpy(line, tmp); // копируем строку, но в tmp второй байт не нулевой.
// Поэтому, функция strcpy будет копировать, пока его не найдет.
// Это может быть как третий, так и сотый, так и тысячный байт.
// но обычно такое сильно не нравится ОС. И будет падение.
line[i] = c;
line[i + 1] = '\0'; // а вот он и нолик.
}
```

Самое простое, что как мне кажется все исправит - поправить здесь `line[0] = ' ';`, добавив `line[1] = '\0';`.

Судя по коду, вы пытаетесь переизобрести realloc.

P.S.

Когда Вы пишете вот так

```
char *line = "";
```

и компилятор не ругается, самое время сменить компилятор. Дело в том, что строка `""` - это `const char*`, а присваивание ёё `char*` печально.

Как сделать по простому - пусть Ваша функция возвращает указатель на строку

```
char* func(...) {
  char* x = malloc(100);
  //...
  return x;
}
//-----------
char * line = func(...);

//
free(line);
```

Но этот способ имеет один недостаток - вызывающая функция "как бы знает о внутренностях". Обычно для этого free заворачивают в специальную свою функцию, которая "знает, как освободить память".

Comment: Да, замечание уместное, спасибо. Исправил. Но проблема осталась. Смысл вопроса не в проблеме выделения памяти, а в запихивании этой части программы в функцию. Как мне в этой функции заполнить строку и потом передать ее в main? Как передать из main объявленный мною указатель (char *line = "";)?